# Strange behavior animating a UIView using [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration]

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

I'm trying to create an effect where three arrows go from visible to invisible alternatively.

I made a simple algorithm where every arrow would start from a different alpha value (if there is 3 arrows, the first one would start at alpha=1, the second one at alpha=0.6667, the third one at alpha=0.3337). I then start a key frame animation that:

- Change the arrow opacity from its current alpha to 0 (the duration is computed)
- Set instantly the arrow opacity to 1
- Change the arrow opacity from 1 to the first value set

However it seems that some step are skipped for some reason.

A simple example:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 0.5;
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 0;
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 1;
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 0.5;
    }];

} completion:nil];
```

In that case it should go to 0.5 instantly, 0.5 to 0 in 1 second, go to 1 instantly, 1 to 0.5 in 1 second. It should therefore do a seamless transition that looks like the view is appearing and disappearing but it looks like the animation gets stuck on alpha=0.5 for a few time.

Theoretically, the effect should be the same as if using this key frame animation:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 1;
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
        _animatedView.alpha = 0;
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is similar to using animation groups with relative animation start and duration offset. I tried to do the same once before. trying to animate a seamless transition between 4 different paths within a shape layer. My experience is that they do not work properly for some reason (I tried a lot). So then I wrote my own completion block logic for the layers and within that I triggered one animation after the completion of other. The code looked a bit stupid, but the animation worked like a charm:). So maybe you can try along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to animate N views in the same way:

```
CGFloat count = [self.animatedViews count];
CGFloat period = 1.0f / count;

__weak NSArray *weakViews = self.animatedViews;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0f delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; ++index) {
        UIView *animatedView = weakViews[index];

        CGFloat startDelay = period * index;

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0 animations:^{
            animatedView.alpha = startDelay;
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:startDelay animations:^{
            animatedView.alpha = 0.0f;
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:startDelay relativeDuration:0.0f animations:^{
            animatedView.alpha = 1.0f;
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:startDelay relativeDuration:(1.0f - startDelay) animations:^{
            animatedView.alpha = startDelay;
        }];
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is the exact implementation I made and this doesn't work correctly for some reason. The first arrow works correctly the others don't. Although the effect on all the arrows looks kinda OK, if you look at each of the arrow you will see that some don't do a seamless alpha transition from 1 to 0.

Comment: So animation of all arrows (except first) is not enough seamless? Is this the only problem?

Comment: Yeah, if you look closely, some views never reach 0 and stay stuck on their start alpha for a few time.

Comment: The problem could be in calculation of period (CGFloat period = 1.0f / count;) where numerator should be always 1. It's not the same as duration.

Comment: Before I sent an answer, I'd checked the code on simulator. And there wasn't anything like "some views never reach 0". Please, make sure everything is the same.